# conditional without a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

While learning Python I stumbled upon a conditional statement that doesn't have a full condition and I can't seem to figure out the use.

`if number:
     print ("2")`

What is being compared to `number`? I can't seem to figure out when it's true and when it's false.

Comment: This basically just checks if the value of *number* isn't Null. If number has a value (doesn't matter what value except Null or None) it prints "2".

Comment: Should be true if it's not equal to 0. Right?

Comment: no, could be `None`, empty list/tuple/dict, everything that is "falsy"

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)...